# Cannot require non-native module in electron child_process fork

Tags: node.js, electron, child-process

I'm using a child_process fork in my Electron app to perform a heavy task without slowing the user interface.

My child_process exits as soon as I try this line:

```
const sqlite3 = require('@journeyapps/sqlcipher').verbose();
```

This works properly, but when I package my application into an asar file using electron-packager and electron-rebuild, it doesn't.

I don't get any error, the child_process 'error' event isn't triggered, but the 'exit' is triggered with code 1.

I assume the process fails to find the module because of the asar file and therefore a fatal error happens when I'm trying to use it.

Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

I think this is similar to this question here, please check the link. You can use child.stderr data event handler to catch the error and debug.

[Node child process exits immediately after packing the electron app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51639238/node-child-process-exits-immediately-after-packing-the-electron-app/51641160#51641160)

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! Is there a similar solution for "fork" ? I think stderr is only available with exec

Comment: Ok I have figured out how to use sterr, but I don't see anything. I put a console.log on the first line of my child_process, and I'm getting nothing in the stout.on('data') event...

This problem occurs only after I install my app on Windows with an installer made with electron-winstaller

Comment: Did you find a way to catch the error when using fork?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply, but no, I didn't find where the error came from, I ended up using a new BrowserWindow instead of a child process. Thanks for replying though, have a nice day!

Comment: You can set the 'silent: true' option to capture the error while using fork.